# Is there any on screen keyboard to use on inspiron duo in tablet mode?

Tags: keyboard, multi-touch, tablet, inspiron, touchscreen

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on a Dell inspiron Duo Hybrid. Almost everything works fine except for the accelerometer.
But when using Ubuntu in tablet mode, I couldn't find anyway to have a onscreen keyboard automatically appear when typing is required, eg. pointing to the address bar in browser.
I am a total Ubuntu Newbie!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Answers to this question: [Onscreen keyboard? (like OSX's Keyboard Viewer)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59767/onscreen-keyboard-like-osxs-keyboard-viewer/59771#59771) May refer to what you are looking for.

Placed here for your convenience:

> [**xvkbd**](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/) is an option... http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/xvkbd
>
> > xvkbd is a virtual (graphical) keyboard program for X Window System
> >     which provides facility to enter characters onto other clients
> >     (softwares) by clicking on a keyboard displayed on the screen. This
> >     may be used for systems without a hardware keyboard such as kiosk
> >     terminals or handheld devices. This program also has facility to
> >     send
> >     characters specified as the command line option to another client.
>
> [image]
>   *Illustration is from the net.*
>
> The same as [**matchbox-keyboard-im**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/matchbox-keyboard-im)
>
> > Matchbox-keyboard is an on-screen 'virtual' or 'software' keyboard,
> >     designed for touch-screen devices running X.
> >
> > Matchbox is a base environment for the X Window System running on
> >     non-desktop embedded platforms such as handhelds, set-top boxes,
> >     kiosks and anything else for which screen space, input mechanisms or
> >     system resources are limited.
> >
> > This package provides a GTK+ input module for use with
> >     Matchbox-keyboard or other on-screen keyboards.
>
> [image]
>
> *Illustration is from the net*
>
> Both they are in my repositories on Natty but further information can
>   be reached on the official websites.
>
> I remember to have used one of these when installed Jaunty on a Touch
>   Screen HP Laptop, and can inform that it works pretty fine.
>
> I hope this help.
>
> Good luck!

Additional answers coming from other users can be found in the original question.

Good luck!