# Onscreen keyboard like behaviour of regular keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input, internationalization

When I hold down a key on a regular keyboard, the key gets repeated over and over. I do see the advantages of that for an electrical typewriter. 
On Android (and other glass pecking devices) when I hold down a key it shows me letter variations like u ü û ů.

Is there such functions for Ubuntu? Show the variations with a number next to it (left,  right,  top,  below) like double byte input and insert on number or click?

**Update**: Mac OS/X does exactly that. If that's part of Darwin (??) it could be ported?
[image: How it looks on the Mac]

Comment: BTW, Gmail also does this now.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the onscreen keyboard like on OS/X, but a close second, fulfilling my special character needs. When you use  *English (international with AltGr dead keys)* you can type the special characters in two ways. AltGr is usually the right Alt key (in continental European keyboards labeled AltGr):

- hit AltGr together with the "extension" ' or ` or ^ and then the base character a e i o u etc.
- hit AltGr together with the base key or an adjacent key - based on what you want. AltGr+u result in û AltGr+y results in ü

So a bit of a learning step but close enough for daily use ([see also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333227/type-french-accents-with-us-international-keyboard)). For viewing the keyboard on screen [check this askUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59767/onscreen-keyboard-like-osxs-keyboard-viewer).